# 3 questions about topology on metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading a textbook about topology on metric space. I came over the following three *'Prove or Disprove'* questions. Please:

1) comment on my work on the first two questions or leave me your own solution so that I can learn from you;

2) provide your thoughts on the third question, which I cannot complete.

Questions:

> Prove or disprove the followings:
>
> 1) Let $X$ be a metric space and $S, T \subset X$. $(S \cup T)'=S' \cup T'$.
>
> 2) Let  $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $T \subset S$ is closed and
>   bounded, then $T$ is compact.
>
> 3) Every bounded, infinite subset of a metric space has accumulation
>   point.

Definition:

$S'$: the derived set of S, where it contains all the accumulation points of S.

*Compact*: A subset $S$ of a metric space is *compact* if every open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover.

My work:

> 1. True.Assume $x \in (S \cup T)'$. Then for any $r>0$, $B(x,r) \cap
>    > (S \cup T)\setminus \{ x \} \neq \emptyset$.We further assume $x
>    > \notin S'$. It suffices to show $x \in T'$.  Note that $$B(x,r) \cap
>    > (S \cup T)\setminus \{ x \} \neq \emptyset$$ $$\Rightarrow (B(x,r)
>    > \cap S\setminus \{ x \}) \cup (B(x,r) \cap T\setminus \{ x \}) \neq
>    > \emptyset$$ $$\Rightarrow (B(x,r) \cap T\setminus \{ x \}) \neq
>    > \emptyset$$ since $x \notin S'$. Thus, $x \in T'$ as desired.
>      Conversely, assume $x \in (S' \cup T')$. Then $x \in S'$ or $x \in
>    > T'$. WLOG, we assume $x \in S'$. It implies for any $r>0$, $B(x,r)
>    > \cap S\setminus \{ x \} \neq \emptyset$. It implies $B(x,r) \cap
>    > (S\cup T)\setminus \{ x \} \neq \emptyset$. Thus, $x \in (S \cup T)'$.
> 2. False. Take $S = \mathbb{R}$, $T= [0,1]$. $T$ is obviously closed and bounded, but $T$ is not compact. To see that, $\{ [\frac{1}{n}, 1-
>    > \frac{1}{n}] : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an open cover of $T$ but it has
>      no finite subcover.
> 3. No idea! The question makes me think of the *Bolzano-Weierstrass Property* but I simply feel that it is a wrong statement.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thank you all for answering my questions! But I then I now don't know if question 2 is true or not. Does it mean that the statement is true?

---

Comment: Your second statement is incorrect. $[0,1]$ is compact. Note that your cover doesn't include $0$ nor $1.$

Comment: With respect to your second and third questions, is the metric space complete?

Comment: **Hint**: For both (2) and (3), consider the subspace $(0,1)$ of the reals. This will allow your approach in part (2) to work, and that approach should give you an idea for part (3).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint for 3): Think of a sequence in the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$ trying to converge to an irrational.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your proof seems OK to me. The statement seems well proven.
2. Not true. $[0,1]$ is a compact set. Your cover is a cover of $(0,1)$, not of $[0,1]$.
3. The statement is true for real numbers, but what about in general? For example, what if you would have a rational sequence limiting toward an irrational number?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a little problem in your proof. You assume that $x \not\in S'$ and then conclude that $B(x, r) \cap S \backslash \{ x \} = \varnothing$. However, this is not correct, since in general (if $S$ contains at least one element except $x$), if you take $r$ big enough, the LHS is certainly not empty. But it is quite easy to fix this: under your assumption, take $r$ small enough so that $B(x, r) \cap S \backslash \{ x \} = \varnothing$ does hold. Then your proof works.

The other two points have been answered well by others.